# How to send value inside the variable for key for post request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, json.net, jwt

```
change(point,value) {
      console.log(point, value)
      axios.post('http://localhost/' + point, {    
          point: value
      })
      .then(function (response) {
          currentObj.output = response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          currentObj.output = error
      });
    }
```

value inside **point = K1 value = 7**

while sending response

```
{         
      point : 7               
}
```

but i want the response to be like this.

```
{         
      K1 : 7               
}
```

how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of point : value it should be **[point] : value**

```
change(point,value) {
      console.log(point, value)
      axios.post('http://localhost/' + point, {    
         [point]: value
      })
      .then(function (response) {
          currentObj.output = response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          currentObj.output = error
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some syntax errors.

- `http:localhost` should be `http://localhost`
- The correct way to post using axios is: `"http://localhost/"+point, { point: value }`

I would suggest you to format the response the way you want inside the API

Comment: formatting is not the issue when I copied something happened, ill edit it.
the question is different, I want the content inside the point to be sent as the key value to the request. (K1)